# Changed Settings Config now Django Static files isnt working

Tags: django, django-settings, django-staticfiles

So I updated my project settings with the following scheme

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

/settings
  base.py
  prod.py
  dev.py
```

Is this the correct STATICFILES_DIRS settings for the above configuration?

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "site_media", "static"),
]

STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"
```

The templates render just fine using

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),
]
```

So I'm a little turned around as to why my css files arent working

Home.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/home.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change your `PROJECT_ROOT` to something like this:

```
# cwd is settings. determine project path
cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
PROJECT_ROOT = cwd[:-9] # chop off "settings/"
```

That should get your project root where you want it. Also, what link is being created on the front end when you try to use `{{STATIC_URL}}`?

You might want to check out [this link](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings) for more information on splitting up the settings.py file.

Comment: With regard to your question, when I visit the url the page renders and loads my site_base.html template but no css or javascipt static files load.